# How do I count how many negative elements are in a circular doubly linked list?

Tags: java, list

I would like to use `list.negativeNumbers();` to call out the part of a code, which counts how many negative numbers are in a list.

```
public void negativeNumbers(){
    int negative = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++){
        if (i < 0) {
            negative = negative + 1;
        }
        System.out.println("There are "+ negative +" negative elements in the list!");  
    }
}
```

Can you help me in creating a method, that could count negative numbers in the list the correct way?

Comment: What list? Show us your list.

Comment: You confuse a index/position integer with the value at that position. However it is not a ood idea to address a LinkedList with an index, at all.

Comment: I am using this one http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-circular-doubly-linked-list/

Comment: @eckes I know.... :( How do I get the value of the integer at an exact index?

Comment: The whole idea of a LinkedList is to NOT use an index at all. With a collection you can use get(x), but internally it is implemented as iterating the list from the start, so it is not good to use it if you can instead iterate it yourself. (This is typically the main point about talking about LinkedLists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void negativeNumbers(){
    int negative = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++){
        if (i < 0) {
            negative = negative + 1;
        }
        System.out.println("There are "+ negative +" negative elements in the list!");  
    }
}
```

You will learn better by working out the solution for yourself.

Your code as presented is a good start but lacks:

- a defined list of values to test.
- a definition of the size of the list (use list.size()).
- proper indexing of the list to access values to test (use list.get(i) or list[i]).
- a test of each element in the list to determine its negativity.  Your code tests whether the list increment variable is < 0.
- negative = negative + 1 is ok, but simpler to write ++negative.

Here's a simple example:

import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class negnum {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList();
    nums.add(0);
    nums.add(10);
    nums.add(-10);
    nums.add(20);
    nums.add(-20);
    nums.add(30);
    nums.add(-30);
    nums.add(40);
    nums.add(-40);
    nums.add(50);   

    int negs = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
        int n = nums.get(i);
        if (n < 0) {
            ++negs;
            System.out.println(n);
        }        
    }
    System.out.println(negs +" negatives");  
    }
}

c:\dev>java negnum
-10
-20
-30
-40
4 negatives
```

Comment: and: not use index access at all as it has quadratic runtime complexity.

Comment: Thank you! I do would love to figure this out myself, yet even using `linkedList.get(i) < 0` shows up as an error. It says the method get(int) is undefinied, I thought it was supposed to work as a built-in tool?

Comment: All the problems you are seeing with the answers come from the fact that your linked list does not follow Collection conventions (no positional get, no Iterator, ...)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a list of integers you should not be doing "i < 0" but rather the number at index of i. If you were to do that, you would also want to do "< size" rather than "<= size" or else you would run into an IndexArrayOutOfBounds.

Comment: It is a list of integers. What should I type instead of `(i<0)`? Thank you a lot in advance! I'm new to this.

Comment: If it is a List or ArrayList, use listName.get(i) < 0. If it is an array use listName[i] < 0.

Comment: using `linkedList.get(i) < 0` shows up as an error. It says the method get(int) is undefinied, I thought it was supposed to work as a built-in tool?

Comment: What type of object is linkedList? (If you do not know what I mean, respond with the declaration of the variable.)

Comment: Is this what you mean?
    
        /* Class linkedList */
    class linkedList{
        protected Node start;
        protected Node end ;
        public int size;

        /* Constructor */
        public linkedList(){
            start = null;
            end = null;
            size = 0;
        }

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your double linked list is implemented, but if it extends the normal `List<Integer>` interface it would look like:

```
final Integer ZERO = Integer.valueOf(0);

int countNegativeElements() {
  return stream().filter(MyList::isNegative).count();
}

static boolean isNegative(Integer i) {
  return i.compareTo(ZERO) < 0;
}
```

with streams. More traditionally with an collection for-each (or an iterator for-each):

```
int countNegativeElements() {
  int count = 0;
  for(Integer i : this) { // or iterator()
    if (isNegative(i)) count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

This does not expect concurrent modifications and is optimized for collections where iterating is the fastest access. If you have a simple type list then you can replace `isNegative` with a simple `< 0`.

This [article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2461744/java-language/java-language-iterating-over-collections-in-java-8.html) here talks about different ways to iterate a collection.

In my code I assumed you will add the method directly to your list implementation class. Replace `this` or `this.iterator()` or `this.stream()` with your actual list instance if it is external.

**Update:**

I just saw your [link to the actual linked list you are using](http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-circular-doubly-linked-list/), this would look like this (hand made iteration):

```
int countNegativeElements() {
  Node n = start;
  int count = 0;
  while(n != null) {
    if (n.getData() < 0) count++;
    n = n.getLinkNext();
  }
  return count;
}
```

Using `null` since there is no `hasLinkNext()` which would be typical for homework :)

I don't think it is a particular good idea to work with implementations which do not fit in the Collections framework, but maybe it is required to keep the lessons simple.

Comment: anything I write in the place of `this` comes out as an error, saying that it cannot be resolved or is not a field... What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: @DanielFalk I used the methodology from the LinkedList implementation you linked.